# Работа с изображениями в c++

Tags: графика, c++, graphics

Посоветуйте библиотеки для работы с изображениями (накладывание эффектов аля инстаграмм, корректировка) в языке  C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)
- [libraw](http://www.libraw.org/) - работа с raw
- [Gegl](http://cairographics.org/cairomm/)- (Generic Graphics Library) is a graph based image processing framework.
- [Cairomm](http://cairographics.org/cairomm/) - c++ wrapper для Cairo

Ну это первое что приходит на ум

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV - mast know =)